# Android Studio - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find button's onClick method

Tags: java, android, sql, database, logcat

I am trying to execute the "sendMessage()" method when the "button_addData" button is clicked, but every time I try, the app crashes. The purpose is to create a database and store all the inputted data in it. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
package com.example.rishi.ibplanner;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.util.Calendar;

public class EnterDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editDescription, editDuration;
Spinner spnPriority;
Long deadlineDate;
Button btnAddData;

public long sendValue() { 
    DatePicker spnDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datepicker_deadline);
    int day = spnDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = spnDatePicker.getMonth();
    int year = spnDatePicker.getYear();

    Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, month); // 0-11 so 1 less
    thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //conversion into days
    return days;
}
    // Button to proceed
    public void sendMessage(View view) {



        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this); 

        editDescription = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_description);
        editDuration = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_duration);
        spnPriority = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.priority_spinner);

        deadlineDate = sendValue();

        btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_addData);
        addData();
}




public void addData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editDescription.getText().toString(),
                            editDuration.getText().toString(),
                            spnPriority.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            deadlineDate.toString());
                    if (isInserted = true)
                        Toast.makeText(EnterDataActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(EnterDataActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

public void cancelActivity (View view) {
    onBackPressed();
}
```

}

And the xml, for just the button, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rishi.ibplanner.EnterDataActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_addData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/add" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And the error I receive in the logcat is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method  sendMessage[EnterDataActivity](View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button_addData'
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Can show code snippet where oncreate code is written,and there is no need to add listener on that button as you are already specified it by XML onclick attribute so remove the listener from addData

Answer (score 0):

What is showing up when you start the app ? Is the button appearing ? 
Because you don't inflate your XML file in your activity, so the XML cannot navigate to the sendMessage() method.

You should add the following to your activity :

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)
```